# Dynanically change tailwindcss color based on user input in Vue3/Nuxt3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css, nuxtjs3

I am trying to build a way for a user to define the primary color of the website. When defining my tailwind classes, I want to use something like `bg-primary-600` rather than hard coding a color, so that when the value for `primary` changes, it will update the style.

Here I have my test environment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-qinx8e?file=tailwind.config.js

For those who don't want to open the link

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: [
    './components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}',
    './layouts/**/*.vue',
    './pages/**/*.vue',
    './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
    './nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
    './app.vue',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // This should be changed by the user instead of hard coding
        primary: colors.blue,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

app.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="bg-red-600 h-16 mb-4">HELLO WORLD</div>
    <div class="bg-primary-600 h-16 mb-4">HELLO WORLD</div>
    <button class="bg-blue-200 rounded-lg p-4 mx-2" @click="myColor = 'blue'">
      Blue
    </button>
    <button class="bg-green-200 rounded-lg p-4" @click="myColor = 'green'">
      Green
    </button>
    <body class="mx-2">
      My color is: {{ myColor }}
    </body>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const myColor = ref('orange');
</script>
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to dynamically change the color in Tailwind. I'm able to hard code a value like in my example, but I cannot assign this value to a reactive variable and have it update.

I cannot figure out how to make the myColor ref update the color in tailwind. *Note* that I don't want to update it just in the page, I need to be able to update tailwind so that any reference to primary, regardless of the page or component will have the correct color.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CSS variables to achieve that

In your tailwind config, set primary as a CSS var:

```json
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        // This should be changed by the user instead of hard coding
        primary: 'var(--color-primary)',
        // This will extend functionality of your color
        // so you can use opacity on it like text-secondary/80
        // var has to have rgb in it not hex color like: --color-info: 14 165 233;
        secondary: 'rgb(var(--color-secondary) / <alpha-value>)'
      },
    },
  },
```

Then you can override the var in the app using `style.setProperty`:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="bg-primary h-16 mb-4">HELLO WORLD</div>
    <button class="bg-blue-200 rounded-lg p-4 mx-2" @click="myColor = 'blue'">
      Blue
    </button>
    <button class="bg-green-200 rounded-lg p-4" @click="myColor = 'green'">
      Blue
    </button>
    <body class="mx-2">
      My color is: {{ myColor }}
    </body>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
const colors = {
  blue: '#0077FF',
  green: '#00DD77',
};
const myColor = ref('orange');
watch(myColor, (color) => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--color-primary', colors[color]);
});
</script>

<style>
:root {
  --color-primary: #ff9900;
}
</style>
```

Note that tailwind will not be able to determine the color variations, so you cannot use `bg-primary-500` or `bg-primary-200` you need to drop the number i.e. `bg-primary` and `text-primary` etc.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to accomplish it using tailwind colors or at least maintaining the ability to add the number i.e. `bg-primary-200`. Seems that I'm best off adding the logic to Vue to switch between colors based on the value of `myColor`.

Tailwind config is just a javascript file, perhaps there's another solution. Do you know of a way to change the value of the color based on a variable, perhaps like this? https://pastebin.com/HBqLuwGg

Comment: @TaylorFinklea Yes, the Tailwind config is essentially a JavaScript file. However, it remains inaccessible to your Vue app’s logic. This file operates solely within the Node.js runtime environment and is responsible for generating the required classes for your app during compile/build time. The solution above is the best if not the only solution that I can think of.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out how to dynamically set the primary color and still maintain the ability to do things like `bg-primary-600`. Now I just need to figure out how to make the user able to change this value, but that's a cookie issue not a tailwindcss issue.

I split up the export into separate blocks, so that I could dynamically define my theme block based on the value of a variable.

tailwind.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');
const color = 'blue';

exports.darkMode = 'class';

exports.content = [
  './components/**/*.{js,vue,ts}',
  './layouts/**/*.vue',
  './pages/**/*.vue',
  './plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
  './nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
  './app.vue',
];

if (color === 'blue') {
  exports.theme = {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.blue,
      },
    },
  };
}
if (color === 'green') {
  exports.theme = {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.green,
      },
    },
  };
}
if (color === 'orange') {
  exports.theme = {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.orange,
      },
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: the tailwind colors and the classes are generated compile-time. This solution will not work. If you really want to use the tailwind color palette (with the numbers ie `red-500`) you will need to have the classes managed by vue (ie, `color == 'blue' ? 'bg-blue-800 text-blue-300' : 'bg-green-800 text-green-300'`) this is going to be less "manageable" than using vars